# How should I restore /var/cache?

Tags: backup, rsync, cache, restore

I just restored my Raspberry Pi server from an `rsync` image. During the backup, I had excluded `/var/cache/*`, thinking that this would restore an empty directory. This worked, but when I rebooted, a process complained that it couldn't write to it in the following mail.

```
Subject: status report from ddclient@raspberrypi
...
WARNING:  updating <url>.dynu.com: nochg: No update required; unnecessary attempts to change to the current address are considered abusive
FATAL:    Cannot create file '/var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache'. (No such file or directory)
```

I checked the permissions of `/var/log`, which were consistent with my Arch desktop system.

```
$ ls -ld /var/cache/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 15 13:23 /var/cache/
```

Do I have to do anything else? If the permissions are `a-w`, then how can non-root processes write in here?

Comment: Did you try to manually add the ddclient folder? on my machine the folder has 755 permissions and is owned by root.

Comment: @chthonous I haven't yet, but I was considering doing so. My question was more generic. How do I prevent errors in general, and should I have excluded something else (e.g. `/var/cache/*/*`)?

Comment: (N.B. I think `/var/cache/*/*` wouldn't really work conceptually, because there are nested directories within some of these first-level directories.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/var/cache` is not a free-for-all like `/var/tmp`. Each service that requires it has a subdirectory in `/var/cache` with appropriate permissions for it to store files.

On Debian and derived distributions, you can run `dpkg -S /var/cache` to find what packages have set up directories under `/var/cache`, and `apt-get --reinstall install PACKAGE_NAME …` to reinstall these packages and re-create the directories under `/var/cache`.

Some applications repopulate their cache on the fly. Others need to have the cache filled explicitly; this is often done by a cron job. A few need to be populated manually; for example, to use `apt-file`, you'll first need to run `apt-file update` as root.

There is one piece of `/var/cache` on Debian that cannot be reconstructed: `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat`. This file contains the answers that you gave during the installation of Debian packages. This is a [long-standing bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=247134) in Debconf.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (+1). I like the idea of running `dpkg -S /var/cache`. However, `/var/cache/debconf` was repopulated automatically for me on reboot. (This includes `config.dat` `config.dat-old` `passwords.dat` `templates.dat` `templates.dat-old`.)

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately I still had a copy of the corrupted filesystem, so I had some idea of what should go in `/var/cache` for my system.

```
cd /var/cache
sudo mkdir apache2 apt ddclient debconf dictionaries-common fontconfig ldconfig man modsecurity
sudo chmod a=,u=rwx ldconfig
sudo chmod g=rsx man
sudo chown man man
sudo chown www-data modsecurity
sudo mkdir apache2/mod_cache_disk 
sudo chown www-data:www-data apache2/mod_cache_disk
```

After `apt-get update` and a reboot, most of these directories were repopulated. However, there were several files missing in `man`, so I repopulated it with

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install man
```

I also found that `dictionaries-common` and `fontconfig` were now empty, but I didn't worry about those, since I had no idea what they were doing on my headless server anyway! (Possibly ownCloud's dependency on Libreoffice.)

This information is probably specific to my system. In the future, I won't exclude `/var/cache` from backups.

Comment: I had a few directories in `/var/cache` symlinked to a RAID0, including `man` since I knew `/var/cache/man` doesn't have anything that can't be regenerated.  But it was more complicated than I expected to do the re-generating: reinstalling `man` without doing the chown / chmod first didn't work.  But *with* that, it worked fine.