# Restore /var/cache files

Tags: debian, cache, restore

I've accidentally deleted all contents of /var/cache files. I managed to reinstall most by doing `dpkg -S /var/cache` and `apt-get --reinstall install PACKAGE_NAME` (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150487/how-should-i-restore-var-cache)) on every package that I've found.

I still have some missing files into some directories. I re-created them but after rebooting, the problem was still here. Those are the packages with some files missing:

- bind
- dictionaries-common
- fontconfig
- ldconfig

Any ideas on how to force them to regenerate their files?

Comment: Actually the [definition of `/var/cache` in the file hierachy standard](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/fhs/fhs-2.3.html#VARCACHEAPPLICATIONCACHEDATA) is that way that it shouldn't hurt if you delete any file under `/var/cache`.

Comment: So i should not worry about it? Thanks.

Comment: Nope. At least I wouldn't. :-) And if I'd find something which breaks due to an empty `/var/cache`, I'd write a bug report. ;-) (Actually `apt` had such a bug until a few years ago. It refused to work, if the directory `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/` didn't exist. But that's history.)

Comment: that's not what the accepted answer here says: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23156/can-i-safely-remove-var-cache